Ошибка при запросе к oauth.vk.com
При попытке произвести запрос к oauth.vk.com из приложения (запущенного через docker container), вывод ошибку: aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host oauth.vk.com:443 ssl:default [None]. Делали запрос к https://example.com всё нормально, также локально тоже всё работает или через curl. Приложение зарегестрированно и redirect_uri указан верно, ведь если попытаться делать это руками, то всё ОК


Зайди на oauth.vk.com и скачай сертификат в разделе "Разное"


Поменяй расширение файла на .crt
Скопируй файл сертификата командой

$ sudo cp vk-com.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/


Поставь пакет для работы с сертификатами

$ sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates


Обнови хранилище сертификатов

$ sudo update-ca-certificates -v

Пробрось сертификат в докер контейнер, и запусти эти команды
